# How to plot chosen vertices and total number of edges

Tags: r, igraph

I'd like to plot two selected nodes and all their edges, not only the ones that connect these two nodes directly. For example:

```
library(igraph)
o <- read.table(text="
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
A   0   1   0   1   0   1   1
B   1   0   1   1   0   1   0
C   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
D   1   1   0   0   1   0   0
E   0   0   0   1   0   1   1
F   0   1   0   0   1   0   1
G   1   0   1   0   1   1   0", header=TRUE)

mat <- as.matrix(o)
g <- graph.adjacency(mat, mode="undirected", weighted = T, add.rownames = T)
```

I'm able to choose two nodes of g using the codes below, but the plot includes only the edges that connect them directly. I want them all.

```
g2 <- induced_subgraph(g, c("A","E"))
plot(g2)
```

How do I plot the two vertices, and **all** of their edges? Also, how do I choose path distance for each vertex?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "choose" path distance. But, I can help you with your first question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(igraph)

o <- read.table(text="
                A   B   C   D   E   F   G
                A   0   1   0   1   0   1   1
                B   1   0   1   1   0   1   0
                C   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
                D   1   1   0   0   1   0   0
                E   0   0   0   1   0   1   1
                F   0   1   0   0   1   0   1
                G   1   0   1   0   1   1   0", header=TRUE)

mat <- as.matrix(o)
g <- graph.adjacency(mat, mode="undirected", weighted = T, add.rownames = T)
plot(g)

# get 1st connections of A and E (their friends)
vertices_input = c("A","E")                    # specify vertices of interest
ids = as.numeric(E(g)[from(vertices_input)])   # get the ids of the edges from g that correspond to those vertices
g2 = subgraph.edges(g, ids)                    # keep only those edges from g as a sub-graph g2
plot(g2)

# get up to 2nd connections of A and E (friends of friends)
nms = V(g2)$name                      # get names of vertices of your sub-graph g2 (main vertices and 1st connections)
ids = as.numeric(E(g)[from(nms)])     # get the ids of the edges from g that correspond to main vertices and 1st connections
g3 = subgraph.edges(g, ids)           # keep only those edges from g as a sub-graph g3
plot(g3)
```

Comment: Hey AntoniosK, this worked perfectly well -- thanks. Do you know how to plot not only the friends, but also the friends of the friends of the two selected nodes?

Comment: Yes, that follows the same approach. Instead of using only your main vertices (A and E) you use A, E and all 1st connections (i.e friends). I'll update my answer.